# Start the Tailwind build

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm, tailwind-css

`Tailwind> npm run build`

Output:

```
> build
> npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./public/styles/app.css --watch
> Rebuilding...
> Done in 4243ms.
```

After rebuilding, no new changes are applied.

Is it possible that the problem is with VScode???

```
Update npm
Update Node Js
```

Comment: Need a bit more details around the question. Typically if no new changes are applied, there might not be a change in the source file